# Any ideas why initializing a `WebPAnimDecoderNew` would cause a PlatformIO upload failure?

Tags: esp32, webp, firmware, adafruit, platformio

#### Some Context

I am trying to use `libwebp` to decode animated images and display them on an RGB LED Matrix driven by an [Adafruit MatrixPortal](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-matrixportal-m4/overview). My development environment is as follows:

- Mac M2 running Ventura 13.4.1
- PlatformIO Project configured for `board=adafruit_matrix_portal_m4`
- The Adafruit Protomatter library included in `lib_deps`
- `libwebp` included as a submodule in the `lib` directory
- A hard-coded WebP for testing stored in `lib/assets`

The lib structure is modeled after the [tidbyt/hdk](https://github.com/tidbyt/hdk/tree/main) firmware, and the webp asset is pulled directly from there.

#### What's Working

I have been able to successfully compile and upload my `main.cpp` and display a basic text graphic on my LED matrix, so I feel pretty good about my overall architecture.

#### What's Not Working

When I add the single line to initialize a decoder using `libwebp`'s `WebPAnimDecoderNew`, the upload fails around 50% with the message `SAM-BA operation failed`. The following is my working `main.cpp`, with the problem line commented out.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_Protomatter.h>
#include <webp/demux.h>
#include <assets.h>

uint8_t rgbCount = 1;
uint8_t rgbPins[] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
uint8_t addrCount = 4;
uint8_t addrPins[] = {17, 18, 19, 20};
uint8_t clockPin = 14;
uint8_t latchPin = 15;
uint8_t oePin = 16;

uint8_t bitDepth = 6; // 5;

Adafruit_Protomatter matrix(
    128, bitDepth, rgbCount, rgbPins, addrCount, addrPins, clockPin, latchPin, oePin, false);

WebPData webPData;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);

  ProtomatterStatus status = matrix.begin();
  Serial.print("Protomatter begin() status: ");
  Serial.println((int)status);
  if (status != PROTOMATTER_OK)
  {
    for (;;)
      ;
  }
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Refresh FPS = ~");
  Serial.println(matrix.getFrameCount());

  drawTestGraphic();
  drawWebP();

  delay(1000);
}

void drawTestGraphic()
{
  for (int x = 0; x < matrix.width(); x++)
  {
    uint8_t level = x * 256 / matrix.width();
    matrix.drawPixel(x, matrix.height() - 4, matrix.color565(level, 0, 0));
    matrix.drawPixel(x, matrix.height() - 3, matrix.color565(0, level, 0));
    matrix.drawPixel(x, matrix.height() - 2, matrix.color565(0, 0, level));
    matrix.drawPixel(x, matrix.height() - 1, matrix.color565(level, level, level));
  }

  matrix.show();
}

void drawWebP()
{
  WebPDataClear(&webPData);

  webPData.size = ASSET_NOAPPS_WEBP_LEN;
  webPData.bytes = (uint8_t *)malloc(ASSET_NOAPPS_WEBP_LEN);

  memcpy((void *)webPData.bytes, ASSET_NOAPPS_WEBP, ASSET_NOAPPS_WEBP_LEN);

  // Where I want to start decoding...
  // WebPAnimDecoder *decoder = WebPAnimDecoderNew(&webPData, NULL);

  free((void *)webPData.bytes);
}
```

Has anyone experienced this before with `libwebp`? Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue with this line specifically?

Comment: Where did you get a `libwebp` binary built for the AdaFruit?

Comment: @TimRoberts It's the original `libwebp` source code, I am using the convention of including it in the `lib` directory of the PlatformIO project. Some documentation [here](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/sections/platformio/options/directory/lib_dir.html) and an example [here](https://github.com/tidbyt/hdk/tree/main/lib).

Comment: Is it POSSIBLE that the combined executable is simply too large?  You only have 512K bytes of flash, which is a teeny amount in a world used to gigabytes.

Comment: @TimRoberts it's definitely possible; during the upload, however, I get the following message: ```RAM: 2.2% (used 4360 bytes from 196608 bytes); Flash: 17.8% (used 90156 bytes from 507904 bytes)```. This lead me to believe that the executable size should be ok.

Comment: I've also seen [other firmware](https://github.com/acvigue/SmartMatrix-IDF) under similar limitations that have used this library, which makes me optimistic.

Comment: So, you've encoded your webp file into "assets.h" and built it into the executable, right?  How large is the webp file?  Remember that you have even less RAM than you have flash.  Why do you copy it into RAM, instead of just doing `webPData.bytes = ASSET_NOAPPS_WEBP;`?

Comment: @TimRoberts it looks like this was an issue with the amount of memory required for conversion. I realized that the projects I was looking at use an ESP32-S3, which has significantly more (8MB) memory. Even though the MatrixPortal M4 has an ESP32 Wi-Fi co-processor, the RAM accessible to the firmware is in the kb.

Comment: Coincidentally, Adafruit just released a Matrixportal S3 that uses the ESP32S3. I'm going to try to either migrate this project to one of those or to a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@TimRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) pointed out, this is due to the limited memory of the [MatrixPortal M4](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4745). The confusion was in the fact that the M4 has both a ATSAMD51J19 Cortex M4 processor and an ESP32 WiFi co-processor. Even though there is a co-processor, the RAM accessible to the firmware is in limited to kb.

Most of the projects I was looking at use an ESP32-S3, which has significantly more (8MB) memory.

Coincidentally, Adafruit just released a [Matrixportal S3](https://www.adafruit.com/product/5778) that uses the ESP32S3. I'm going to try to either migrate this project to one of those or to a Raspberry Pi.